# Can't coerce class of matrix numbers to integer

Tags: r, oop, class, matrix

I'm writing an adjacency matrix in `R` like so:

```
neighbours <- array(0, c(100,100))
for (i in 1:100) { neighbours[i,i] = 1 }    #reflexive
```

But then I notice that the `class(neighbours)` is `double matrix`. That's going to take up way too much room with a larger matrix. So I want to coerce the type to `integer` or, even better, since this is undirected, `logical`.

But...

```
> class(neighbours[5])
[1] "numeric"
> class(neighbours[5]) <- "integer"
> class(neighbours[5])
[1] "numeric"
```

It is no listen to me!

Comment: You can avoid the `for` loop by using `diag(neighbours) <- 1`.

Comment: This would be another question, you can post it as such.

Answer (score 9):

It's better to not initialize it as numeric in the first place, but if you can't do that, set the `storage.mode`:

```
R> neighbours <- array(0, c(100,100))
R> for (i in 1:100) { neighbours[i,i] = 1 }
R> str(neighbours)
 num [1:100, 1:100] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
R> storage.mode(neighbours) <- "integer"
R> str(neighbours)
 int [1:100, 1:100] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
R> storage.mode(neighbours) <- "logical"
R> str(neighbours)
 logi [1:100, 1:100] TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
```

Answer (score 5):

For those who are still looking for a method to coerce an existing numeric matrix to an integer one:

```
m2 <- apply (m, c (1, 2), function (x) {
  (as.integer(x))
  })
```

The c(1, 2) means apply the function to rows and columns. Testing the class of the elements then gives:

```
> class(m2[1,])
[1] "integer"
> class(m[1,])
[1] "numeric"
>
```

I was looking for something like this because I needed to convert an already existing numerical matrix. It was the result of a very slow computation so modifying the code would have taken me much more time than simply converting the result.

Comment: This will probably be faster as m2 = apply(m, 2, as.integer).  Note that m2 = apply(m, 1, as.integer) will not work; infuriatingly, R transposes the result.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but why not just declare it as a logical array up front?

```
neighbors <- array(FALSE, c(100,100))
diag(neighbors) <- TRUE
```

Comparing the two:

```
> object.size(array(0, c(100,100)))
80200 bytes
> object.size(array(FALSE, c(100,100)))
40200 bytes
```

EDIT: I would be interested to know why a logical array takes up 4B per entry, though...

Comment: Presumably because a logical is a 32-bit word.

Comment: That's because internally the R stores integer and logical SEXPs using C `ints`. There is nothing to be gained here from using the logical data type, storage wise anyway. See the [relevant section](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html#The-_0027data_0027) of the R Internals Manual

Comment: There is a package named "bit" that stores logical vectors as .. wait for it ...  bits.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to fill initially with integer 0 (`0L`) and then replace the diagonal with integer 1, (`1L`)

```
m <- matrix(0L, 100, 100)
diag(m) <- 1L
```

This is half the size of the more straightforward way of creating a diagonal matrix in R:

```
m2 <- diag(1L, 100, 100)

> object.size(m)
40200 bytes
> object.size(m2)
80200 bytes
```

Hence, allocating the integer matrix `m` then changing the diagonal results in the most compact dense matrix.

Comment: Isn't that what I said? I assumed `m2` would end up the same as `m` but clearly it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

There is a sparseMatrix superclass in package Matrix (which is now a standard package). If you wanted a sparse diagonal matrix you could create it with

```
library(Matrix) 
Matrix(diag(1,4) , sparse=TRUE)
#---------
4 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dsCMatrix"

[1,] 1 . . .
[2,] . 1 . .
[3,] . . 1 .
[4,] . . . 1
```

A further thought. If you want to change the mode of a matrix to integer and do not care that it remains dense:

```
> m <- matrix(rnorm(25), 5)
> m[] <- as.integer(m)  
# you do need those square-brackets or the structure becomes a dimensionless vector.
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0   -1    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0    0
[3,]    1    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0   -1    0
```

Yet a further thought prompted by Gavin's comment: If you goal is to represent "adjacency", and its a really big sample space, you may want simply use the sparseMatrix class as a model and instead use a two column matrix with the numbers of the pairs in the columns.. That's not exactly how sparseMatrices holds their row, column and values, but a 2 column storage mode might work for your problem. See the worked examples in the "igraph" package. I would think your problem might be represented as an undirected graph.

Comment: ... with `object.size(Matrix(diag(1, 100), sparse=TRUE))` just 2500 bytes.

Comment: ...versus 80200 bytes for the dense one. Very nice!

Comment: This is a big memory saving but unless what you want to use the matrix for subsequently accepts these sparse matrices then the saving will be lost once you need to convert to a dense representation. Not much of CRAN or base R can use sparse matrices.

Comment: that said, there is no guarantee that the dense integer matrix version will remain integer once it has gone through one or more R functions.

Comment: But if the OP studies the representation of the sparseMatrix class he will probably get insights into the issues he is facing in comming up with a more compact representation of an undirected adjacency "matrix".

Comment: m[] <- as.character(m) will convert integer to character, but m[] <- as.integer(m) will not convert character to integer.